# What precautions should I take when joining my virtual center to Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, virtualization, vmware-vcenter

I have virtual center that manages a few ESX hosts and I would like to join it to my Active Directory domain. What things should I consider when making this move? Is there any reason why I would want to avoid this? I believe it will make user management in virtual-center easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with voretaq7 - there is no reason NOT to put vCenter on a AD-joined server when you have the option.

A word of advice though - vCenter behaves **bad** if you mess around with service accounts etc. I'd strongly consider reinstalling vCenter (and all it's children) if you're planning to join the server to AD and already have vCenter installed.

Comment: Can you expand on your comments about service accounts and the suggestion to reinstall vCenter (and it's children_?

Comment: @ckliborn: I'm not sure what you would like me to say? vCenter has a ton of different services that runs with different user accounts.

Comment: I guess I want to know why you recommend reinstalling vcenter after I join the server to AD

Comment: Because you might experience problems with vCenter services crashing/not starting because of permission issues after the join to AD. I hope this is clear enough for you. Go ahead and put the server in AD without reinstalling, maybe it will work fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason not to do this - In fact from my totally-not-a-windows-admin-and-VirtualCenter-runs-on-a-standalone-box chair it seems to be the Right Thing to do in a Domain environment.

Just be sure you set appropriate VirtualCenter rights for your users and you should be fine...